# Jenkins Pipeline Groovy: Read default parameter value from another job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Within the Groovy code for a pipeline job which manages multiple jobs, is it possible to read the default value of a parameter defined in the configuration of another job?

That is, within pipeline job A, I want to read the default value of param P in job B, which hasn't been scheduled yet.  (This will affect how the request to build B is constructed in job A.)

```
def val = "some-random-prefix" +
          ReadJobParamDefault(job: 'B', parameter: 'paramName') +
          "-some-random-suffix"
def b = build(job: 'B',
              description: 'Some text',
              parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue',
                            name: 'paramName',
                            value: val]])
```

Is there something real for ReadJobParamDefault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that it could be possible to store some Groovy class into a shared library (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) doing something like

```
public static String ReadJobParamDefault(jobName, String parameter) {
    def job = Hudson.instance.getJob(jobName)
    String ret = null;
    if (job != null && parameter != null  && parameter.trim().length() > 0) {
        job.getProperties().values().each {
            if(it instanceof hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty) {
                if (it.getParameterDefinition(parameter) != null) {
                    ret = it.getParameterDefinition(parameter).
                        getDefaultParameterValue().getValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Trying this, but it will take a while - I'm not an admin in this Jenkins so I have to put in a ticket for script approvals for each method that the Groovy sandbox blocks.  Looks like a great starting point, much appreciated.

Comment: Worked!  Thank you very much.

Comment: It worked fine when using my account. But it's not working when executed by other people, any chance this is a permission issue or in-script approval? Thanks for the help.