# How to get default parameter of downstream jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a multijob A, it has some downstream jobs (subA1, subA2, ...). Each downstream job has its own parameters.

When I run job A, all parameters of job A are passed to downstream jobs but their own parameters of downstream jobs (subA1, subA2, ..) does not appear.

How can I make subA1, subA2, ... get their own params ?

Comment: The closest you could get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459821/jenkins-pipeline-groovy-read-default-parameter-value-from-another-job